# Conditional config WP_HOME/WP_SITEURL does not update bloginfo('template_url')?

Tags: themes, templates, directory, mobile, wp-config

### The scenario:

This question relates to Wordpress theme development on a local environment via [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info).

In order to enable mobile device testing via [xip.io](http://xip.io), I have modified my local Wordpress `wp-config.php` file with the following:

```
require_once('b5f-browsers.php');
if( b5f_browser_check('mobile')) {
    define('WP_HOME','http://mysite.dev.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].'.xip.io');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysite.dev.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].'.xip.io');
}
```

*NOTE: Credit for this solution goes to [brasofilo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo) in [this related post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98386/testing-local-server-with-mamp-wordpress-on-mobile-device).*

---

### The problem:

My custom theme's HTML head and footer blocks contain calls to CSS and JavaScript files using the standard `bloginfo('template_url')` function. This works normally when browsing on the host computer.

But on mobile devices, the main site base domain as defined under *WP Admin > Settings > General* is used in the 'template_url' instead of the conditional override as specified in the `wp-config.php` file above.

So I get lines like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.dev/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css">
```

Instead of this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.dev.HOST-IP-ADDRESS.xip.io/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css">
```

---

### A workaround:

Interestingly, I noticed that `bloginfo('wpurl')` returns the correct **xip.io** URL for mobile, and other core Wordpress functions such as `bloginfo('rss_url')` obey the URL override. But `bloginfo('template_url')` just doesn't seem to want to do it.

So as a workaround, I am using `bloginfo('wpurl')` then adding the full path to the theme directory instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css">
```

But this doesn't seem like the right way to go about it...

---

### The question:

Is there a better/correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution... the problem was due to placement of the conditional statement in the `wp-config.php` file.

It needed to be inserted *before* the `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` line near the bottom of the default config file, otherwise the constants are already defined and cannot be redefined.

So final section of the `wp-config.php` file now looks like this:

```
...

/** Add xip.io support for mobile theme testing **/
require_once('b5f-browsers.php');
if( b5f_browser_check('mobile')) {
    define('WP_HOME','http://mysite.dev.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].'.xip.io');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysite.dev.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].'.xip.io');
}

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

My quick guess (that code is rather nightmarish to follow) would be that you need to define `WP_CONTENT_URL` as well, since issue seem to be about content directories.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... didn't solve the issue, but it did lead me on to check other possible problems which helped find the solution (needed to move the conditional statements ABOVE the `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` line in `wp-config.php`).

Comment: Ah, yes, they do mean that _stop editing!_ there. :)